# Change name of source in Enterprise Library Logging

Tags: visual-studio-2013, enterprise-library

I am using Enterprise Library Logging to easly log to my Event Viewer in windows.

But I don't know **how to change the source if possible in Enterprise Library logging to the name of my application** (MyApp for example).

[image: Event Viewer]

I am using a visual editor to easly edit the options in Enterprise Library Logging called: Enterprise Library Configuration as you can see in the picture.

[image: Enterprise Library Configuration]

This is my App.config file that is generated by the Enterprise Library Configuration Editor:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
    <section name="exceptionHandling" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Configuration.ExceptionHandlingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
    <section name="SettingsConfiguration" type="ET.Settings.SettingsConfigurationSection, E-Trace.Settings, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=403b794e0e68acbe" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <loggingConfiguration name="" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="General">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Event Log" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FormattedEventLogTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FormattedEventLogTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        source="Enterprise Library Logging" formatter="Simple Formatter"
        log="Application" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp, Callstack"
        filter="All" asynchronous="true" />
      <add listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.CustomTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        type="ET.Logging.TraceListener.ConsoleTraceListener, E-Trace.Logging, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=403b794e0e68acbe"
        name="ConsoleTraceListener" formatter="Simple Formatter" />
    </listeners>
    <formatters>
      <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        template="{timestamp(local)} -  {severity}  : {message}" name="Simple Formatter" />
    </formatters>
    <categorySources>
      <add switchValue="All" name="General">
        <listeners>
          <add name="ConsoleTraceListener" />
          <add name="Event Log" />
        </listeners>
      </add>
    </categorySources>
    <specialSources>
      <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events" />
      <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category" />
      <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
        <listeners>
          <add name="ConsoleTraceListener" />
        </listeners>
      </errors>
    </specialSources>
  </loggingConfiguration>
  <exceptionHandling>
    <exceptionPolicies>
      <add name="Log Only Policy">
        <exceptionTypes>
          <add name="All Exceptions" type="System.Exception, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
            postHandlingAction="None">
            <exceptionHandlers>
              <add name="Logging Exception Handler" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging.LoggingExceptionHandler, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                logCategory="General" eventId="100" severity="Error" title="Services"
                formatterType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.TextExceptionFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling"
                priority="0" />
            </exceptionHandlers>
          </add>
        </exceptionTypes>
      </add>
      <add name="Log And Notify">
        <exceptionTypes>
          <add name="All Exceptions" type="System.Exception, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
            postHandlingAction="None">
            <exceptionHandlers>
              <add name="Logging Exception Handler" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging.LoggingExceptionHandler, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                logCategory="General" eventId="100" severity="Error" title="Services"
                formatterType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.TextExceptionFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling"
                priority="0" />
            </exceptionHandlers>
          </add>
        </exceptionTypes>
      </add>
    </exceptionPolicies>
  </exceptionHandling>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Change the configuration: `source="Enterprise Library Logging"` to `source="MyApp"`.  You will have to ensure that the EventLog keys are created (e.g. create the registry keys ahead of time or log one message with elevated permissions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anwser is that you need to run the console as administrator once so that it can create the source.

I am using [this](http://randylevy.wordpress.com/2014/10/04/enterpriselibrary-config-for-vs2013/) visual studio 2013 plugin for editing the config on an easy way.

Answer (score 1):

Just going to add, if you want to do this programmatically (instead of in the app.config), the place to change it is in the properties of the EventLog object, as so:

```
// Trace Listeners
var eventLog = new EventLog("Application",
    ".",
    "MyApp Event Logging");
var eventLogTraceListener = new FormattedEventLogTraceListener(eventLog);
```

And then build the rest of your LoggingConfiguration as you otherwise would.